# What do these dotted lines on docked tabs in Visual Studio 2012 mean?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, ide

Okay, let me just say, this isn't super important, but I've really been wondering lately.

The docked tabs in Visual Studio 2012 Express (On the sidebar) have seemingly random red dots/lines to the left of the text. Sometimes they are there and sometimes they aren't.

**EDIT:** A friend of mine said he also has them, however they are green, but that is probably because he uses a different color theme.

Here is an example:

[image: Weird Lines]

Closer:

[image: o3o]

I docked a ton of tabs on purpose, normally I only have 2 over there.

I also noticed a few of them had no lines, but when I moused over them they appeared.

So, Is this a bug? Is this a subtle feature? I have no clue, could this just be something on my computer?

Comment: This looks like a bug to me (albeit a very minor one).  Before i categorically dismiss it as one, though...what are your display settings?  In particular, color depth?

Comment: Actually, never mind.  I have the same dots, and am running with decent display settings.  This is almost definitely a bug.

Comment: Just submitted this as a bug to MS

Comment: Could you confirm the bug is there for standard color scheme?

Comment: Right before I went into options to change it, they went away. Will leave it running in the default theme for a while. @cHao what theme are you using?

Comment: I'm using the "dark" theme, but switched to the "blue" and "light" ones to see what's going on.  The dots appear greenish in the light theme, and red in the others.

Comment: For reference, i went and disabled hardware-accelerated rendering, and the dots went away -- to the point where i'm having a hard time replicating the bug now, even after reenabling acceleration.

Comment: It's a new hidden feature of VS2012, based on highly sophisticated AI algorithms. VS scans your source files continuously and analyses its robustness and correctness. The AI algorithms behind this are so advanced, they developed higher feelings. The red dots and lines express VS's feelings about potential bugs in your code. I suggest you write more unit tests.

Comment: @BartoszKP Oh, Who new it was that Simple. Hah

Comment: Sorry, couldn't resist ;) To write anything slightly related to the topic - I'm using the dark theme and have never seen these red marks :) Maybe OS does matter (Win7 here)?

Comment: @BartoszKP: They're very, very easy to miss.  I've been using VS off and on for a while and never noticed these dots til someone asked about them.  And it appears they only show when hardware acceleration is on, which it might not be if you're on an older or slower machine.

Comment: Yes, probably I could've missed them. Will watch out for them now, just of curiosity. I have i7 with 16 gb ram, I'm not sure about graphics, but windows index is pretty high, so I'm guessing the acceleration is present.

Comment: Well I am using Windows 7 as well, have hardware acceleration on and have an i7 with 8 gb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reply from the ticket a sent to Microsoft

> *Posted by Microsoft on 9/3/2013* at 3:01 PM
>
> Turn off HW acceleration in
> Tools\Options, and turn it back On

Well, thats why they call it a workaround...

Answer (score 0):

Update your video card drivers, those are random "artifacts" from the image generation.  If that doesn't work, but a better video card... or ignore it; or, do as Cyral suggests and turn off HW acceleration.    I'm not a fan of turning off HW acceleration as VS is much more responsive with a decent video card.

Technically, this isn't a bug in VS but rather an issue with your video card.

Comment: I've tried updating them before (3 months ago), the new drivers are messed up and I can't play any games with them (random glitches, textures not showing, game not running at all).

Comment: @Cyral: I guess you have your answer then.  It's been my experience that once you find a video driver set that works you simply don't touch them.  Ever.  Those guys have got the absolute worst track record of broken stuff I've ever seen...  To be fair, I know they are trying to fix problems in games, which are technically due to idiot game programmers, but, they simply don't test the things that programmers regularly use.  If you stick with the standard WHQL drivers from MS then you are usually good in a dev environment. Most issues I've seen were in Management Studio with AMD video.

Comment: So I ripped out the AMD cards and replaced with nVidia ones.  Those have been MUCH better.

Comment: I have an AMD 7470 (Basically a rebranded one of the 6xxx series, I forget which), and it is a laptop :/